# knowing that $F(x)=\int^{x^3}_0\cos({t^2})dt$, how to disprove these statements?

Tags: calculus

First statement: $F(x)=F(-x)$ for every x. 
 
I don't understand why this is false, thinking about the area under the graph of $\cos(t^2)$, it would be equal from both sides and symmetric according to $x=0$. 
Second statement: $F(1)=5$. 

I have no idea how to disprove this, I tried with taking derivative $F'(x)=\cos(x^6)3x^2$, but it's positive in $(0,1]$, so $F(0)=0$, and it can reach $F(1)=5$, knowing that $F(x)$ is increasing since the derivative is positive. 
 Any help and explanation are really appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) An easy calculation shows your function is odd and not even:
$$F(-x)= \int_0^{-x^3} \cos(t^2)dt =-\int_0^{x^3}\cos(t^2) dt = -F(x)$$
where the middle equality follows because $t \mapsto \cos(t^2)$ is an even function.

(2) $F(1)=5$ is impossible because
$$|F(1)| \leq \int_0^{1} |\cos(t^2)|dt \le 1$$

Answer (score 3):

1.- For $x>0$, $-x^3<0$, so $$F(-x)=\int_0^{-x^3}\cos(t^2)dt=-\int_{-x^3}^0\cos(t^2)dt \overset{(*)}{=}-\int_0^{x^3}\cos(t^2)dt=-F(x),$$ where in (*) we have used that $\cos(t^2)$ is even, so $\int_0^a=\int_{-a}^0$

The same occur when $x<0$.

2.- $\cos t^2\le 1$, so $F(1)=\int_0^1\cos t^2\le\int_0^1 dt= 1$ and it cannot be 5.

Comment: It was a misprint

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

0)Assume $F(x) =F(-x)$, i. e. $F$ is even.

$F$ is differentiable:

1)$ F'(x) =-F'(-x);$

We get

$F'(x) =3x^2\cos ((x^3)^2)$, and

$-F'(-x) = -3(-x)^2\cos ((-x)^3)^2).$

$F$ is not even.